# how to show next image in a carousel view in c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a carousel view with next and previous buttons to show the previous and next images. When I am clicking the Next button it doesn't get to next image, it stays the same. Can anyone help me solve this issue.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
// Declare variables. 
public RectTransform window;
public bool startWelcomeScreen;

public RectTransform[] introImages;
private float wide;
private float mousePositionStartX;
private float mousePositionEndX;
private float dragAmount;
private float screenPosition;
private float lastScreenPosition;
private float lerpTimer;
private float lerpPage;

public int pageCount = 1;
public string side = "";

public int swipeThrustHold = 30;
public int spaceBetweenProfileImages = 30;
private bool canSwipe;

public GameObject cartoonWindow;

public Texture2D userPic;
    void Start() {

        wide = cartoonWindow.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.width;

        for(int i = 1; i < introImages.Length; i++){

            introImages[i].anchoredPosition = new Vector2(((wide+spaceBetweenProfileImages)*i),0);

        }

        side = "right";

        startWelcomeScreen = true;

    }

    public void NextButtonIsTapped()
    {

        cartoonWindow.SetActive(true);


    }



    void Update() {

        if(!startWelcomeScreen)
            return;

        lerpTimer=lerpTimer+Time.deltaTime;
        if(lerpTimer<.333){
            screenPosition = Mathf.Lerp(lastScreenPosition ,lerpPage*-1 , lerpTimer*3);
            lastScreenPosition=screenPosition;
        }

        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && Input.mousePosition.y > (Screen.height*0.6173f) && Input.mousePosition.y < (Screen.height*0.91f) ) {
            canSwipe = true;
            mousePositionStartX = Input.mousePosition.x;
        }


        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
            if(canSwipe){
                mousePositionEndX = Input.mousePosition.x;
                dragAmount=mousePositionEndX-mousePositionStartX;
                screenPosition=lastScreenPosition+dragAmount;
            }
        }

        if(Mathf.Abs(dragAmount) > swipeThrustHold && canSwipe){
            canSwipe = false;
            lastScreenPosition=screenPosition;
            if(pageCount < introImages.Length )
                OnSwipeComplete () ;
            else if(pageCount == introImages.Length && dragAmount < 0)
                lerpTimer=0;
            else if(pageCount == introImages.Length && dragAmount > 0)
                OnSwipeComplete () ;
        }

        if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {

            if(Mathf.Abs(dragAmount) < swipeThrustHold) {
                lerpTimer = 0;
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < introImages.Length; i++){

            introImages[i].anchoredPosition = new Vector2(screenPosition+((wide+spaceBetweenProfileImages)*i),0);

            if(side == "right") {
                if(i == pageCount-1) {
                    introImages[i].localScale = Vector3.Lerp(introImages[i].localScale,new Vector3(1.2f,1.2f,1.2f),Time.deltaTime*5);
                    Color temp = introImages[i].GetComponent<Image>().color;
                    introImages[i].GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color(temp.r,temp.g,temp.b,1);
                } else {
                    introImages[i].localScale = Vector3.Lerp(introImages[i].localScale,new Vector3(0.7f,0.7f,0.7f),Time.deltaTime*5);
                    Color temp = introImages[i].GetComponent<Image>().color;
                    introImages[i].GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color(temp.r,temp.g,temp.b,0.5f);
                }
            } else {
                if(i == pageCount) {
                    introImages[i].localScale = Vector3.Lerp(introImages[i].localScale,new Vector3(1.2f,1.2f,1.2f),Time.deltaTime*5);
                    Color temp = introImages[i].GetComponent<Image>().color;
                    introImages[i].GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color(temp.r,temp.g,temp.b,1);
                } else {
                    introImages[i].localScale = Vector3.Lerp(introImages[i].localScale,new Vector3(0.7f,0.7f,0.7f),Time.deltaTime*5);
                    Color temp = introImages[i].GetComponent<Image>().color;
                    introImages[i].GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color(temp.r,temp.g,temp.b,0.5f);
                }
            }
        }


    }

    #endregion
```

I don't get any errors though but it's just don't get to next image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code above I would suggest you create a parent gameobject around the `introImages` and rather move it's anchored position and not move each image. By moving the anchored position of the parent, all the child images will move within the mask.

To include paging buttons to move next and previous, you could do:

```
  void Start () {
        rectTransform = sliderWrapper.GetComponent<RectTransform> (); // parent wrapper
        currentItem = 0; // start x position of the wrapper
        itemWidth = 1000f; // width of the images
        itemCount = sliderWrapper.transform.childCount; // number of images
    }
```

Then in your next and previous methods, you move the parent's `anchoredPosition`:

```
   public void Next () {
        currentItem++; // the next image
        rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2 (-currentItem * itemWidth, 0); // move the x position by the currentItem (the index) multiplied by image width

        prevButton.interactable = true;

        if (currentItem == itemCount - 1) {
            nextButton.interactable = false;
        }
    }

    public void Prev () {
        currentItem--; // previous image
        rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2 (-currentItem * itemWidth, 0); // move the x position by the currentItem (the index) multiplied by image width

        if (currentItem == 0) {
            prevButton.interactable = false;
        }

        if (currentItem < itemCount) {
            nextButton.interactable = true;
        }
    }
```

#### UPDATE

Some steps to help outline the above. Note no animation is in place, it simply jumps to the relevant slider item.

1) Add a GameObject, called Slider below, with a `Rect Mask 2D` component and set the rect transform width/height to match a single image's width/height. This will mask out the overflowing children.

[image]

2) Add a GameObject, called Item Wrapper below, with a `Horizontal Layout Group` component and a `Content Size Fitter` and set properties like below to allow it to scale the game object's rect transform width according to the children and also layout the images horizontally:

[image]

Now all you need to do is update the Slider Wrapper's `anchoredPosition`. This will move the wrapper within the parent Slider GameObject. As the Slider GameObject has a mask on it, we don't see any of the overflowing items.

```
    [SerializeField]
    Button nextButton;

    [SerializeField]
    Button prevButton;

    [SerializeField]
    GameObject sliderWrapper;

    float itemWidth;

    int itemCount;

    int currentItem;

    RectTransform rectTransform;

    void Start () {
        rectTransform = sliderWrapper.GetComponent<RectTransform> ();
        currentItem = 0;
        itemWidth = 1000f; // width of your slider/image
        itemCount = sliderWrapper.transform.childCount;
    }

    public void Next () {
        currentItem++;
        rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2 (-currentItem * itemWidth, 0);

        prevButton.interactable = true;

        if (currentItem == itemCount - 1) {
            nextButton.interactable = false;
        }
    }

    public void Prev () {
        currentItem--;
        rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2 (-currentItem * itemWidth, 0);

        if (currentItem == 0) {
            prevButton.interactable = false;
        }

        if (currentItem < itemCount) {
            nextButton.interactable = true;
        }
    }
```

[image]

#### BONUS

Code to animate the slider:

```
    public void Next () {
        currentItem++;

        prevButton.interactable = false;
        nextButton.interactable = false;

        StartCoroutine (SlideTo (new Vector2 (-currentItem * itemWidth, 0), () => {
            prevButton.interactable = true;

            if (currentItem < itemCount - 1) {
                nextButton.interactable = true;
            }
        }));
    }

    public void Prev () {
        currentItem--;

        prevButton.interactable = false;
        nextButton.interactable = false;

        StartCoroutine (SlideTo (new Vector2 (-currentItem * itemWidth, 0), () => {
            if (currentItem > 0) {
                prevButton.interactable = true;
            }

            if (currentItem < itemCount) {
                nextButton.interactable = true;
            }
        }));
    }

    IEnumerator SlideTo (Vector2 position, Action callback = null, float timeToMove = .5f) {
        var t = 0f;
        while (t < 1) {
            t += Time.deltaTime / timeToMove;

            rectTransform.anchoredPosition = Vector2.Lerp (rectTransform.anchoredPosition, position, t);
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame ();
        }

        if (callback != null) {
            callback ();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for  your answer @SamuelG. However, I created a GameObject and added my Carousel View Script and added all the images into `introImages`. Please see the following image to see if I did it properly. And if I only need to add the `next()` and `prev()` method. thanks. https://imgur.com/a/8u3fFoC

Comment: Also, please see my updated code with the local variables. Because, I dont understand your `Start()` method

Comment: TBH, I think you should redesign this. You are wasting resources by updating the anchor position of every image instead of just updating the parent. I will update the answer to help provide some thought.

Comment: Looking forward for your updated answer.  Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will upvote your answer. :) . How can I select a particular image  with the code of yours?

Comment: Select as in scroll to it, or actually select the image by clicking it?

Comment: actually select the image by clicking it.

Comment: You could just make each image a button and set the `Source Image` property. Then just add an `On Click` event